# python returning type instead of class

Tags: python

I am new in python and i was trying below script

```
"""
>>> x + y  
42  
>>> type(message)  
<class 'str'>  
>>> len(message)  
13  
"""  

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    x = 22  
    y = 20  
    message = str("abcdefghijklm")
    import doctest  
    doctest.testmod()
```

I am getting below error python version is 2.6

```
File "test1.py", line 6, in __main__  
Failed example:  
    type(message)  
Expected:  
    < class 'str'>  
Got:  
    < type 'str'>
```

Can you please suggest why it is type even though i am using str class to create message object ?

Answer (score 3):

Because the `class` keyword is there to make a new type. Take a look at the following:

```
>>> type(type)
<class 'type'>
>>> type(object)
<class 'type'>
```

In python everything is an `object` and this everything inherits from `object`. And as you can see the `type` for object is `type`. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just ask Python, what `str` is.

```
In [1]: type(str)
Out[1]: type
```

Answer (score 1):

"Type" is (mostly) a synonym for "class" in Python. One uses the `class` keyword in order to create new types in Python code.

Comment: does this mean the testcase which I am using "<class 'str'> " is incorrect ? or there is a way I can create a object of class str ? I am assuming here that I don't have to create a custom str class.

Comment: @user258367: It may be correct for an older version of Python, but I haven't found any indication of that yet. Even custom classes use "type" in their repr.